# Using file_get_contents in php file to define variable

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am using the ServerPilot API to apply a self-signed SSL certificate to a ServerPilot App.  I already have the csr, key, and crt files ready to go.  Now I am using the supplied script below to save the contents of the key and crt txt files to a variable which then can be used in the script to save to the ServerPilot App.

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
$clientid = "redacted";
$apikey = "redacted";

$appid = file_get_contents("temp_serverpilot-appid_filtered.txt");

$vardomainname = file_get_contents("temp_serverpilot-domainname.txt");

$sslkey = file_get_contents("/root/certs/$vardomainname/ssl.key");

$sslcert = file_get_contents("/root/certs/$vardomainname/ssl.crt");

$data = array(
    "key" => $sslkey,
    "cert" => $sslcert,
    "cacerts" => null
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);

$ch = curl_init("https://api.serverpilot.io/v1/apps/$appid/ssl");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$clientid:$apikey");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);


$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo json_encode(json_decode($result), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

There are two problems:
1. Using file_get_contents on the $sslkey and $sslcert variables has another variable in the path.  When I run the php script it returns this:

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/root/certs/mydomainredacted.com/ssl.key): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /root/serverpilot-ssl-apply.php on line 11
Warning: file_get_contents(/root/certs/mydomainredacted.com/ssl.key): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /root/serverpilot-ssl-apply.php on line 11
```

2. If I manually enter the domain name in the $sslkey and $sslcert variables to test.  The PHP warnings do not happen, but the script does not execute.

If I test echoing the variables, the file contents of the two ssl files return to the screen just fine.

Comment: Does the file `/root/certs/mydomainredacted.com/ssl.key` exist and is readable by you? It seems you are trying to access `/root`, which only `root` can access. A PHP page (**usually**) runs on the user `www-data` or `apache`, which don't have permissions to access `/root`.

Comment: So `$vardomainname` outputs **exactly** what you expect? can you do a `var_dump($vardomainname);` and verify that the string length is what you expect it to be, please? Maybe there is a newline or other hidden characters...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Yes, the file exists. I am logged in as root.

Comment: On your point 2. When you say you manually enter the domain name in the $sslkey and $sslcert and dont get any php errors (disregarding the rest not worming) points to their being something funky in your text file that's being read in... as @MonkeyZeus pointed out.

Comment: I think its might be the permission issue with php and apache process why don't you copy and these files from root to any of your directory say /var/www/html/ under webserver and try to include form that address

Comment: @MonkeyZeus var_dump returns this: `root@Test:~# php serverpilot-ssl-apply.php

string(18) "mydomain.com
"
null

When I echo, I get the "null" as well, not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: @petebocken Is Apache running as root? If it isn't, you won't get anywhere. If it is, STOP RIGHT NOW (that's a **huge** security hole). Why don't you just copy the file to a directory innaccessible from an URL? (on a default configuration, it would be something like `/var/www/public_html`, and so, you can copy the file to `/var/www`)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'm not sure how I would know that apache is running under root, but I'm sure ServerPilot does not configure it that way.  This php file is located in /root/

Comment: Ah, I suppose the "null" that returns is from the last json_encode echo since it has nothing to return.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus So "string(18)" means 18 characters were returned?  My domain is only 17 characters long.  I confirm the text file is only 17 characters long and no spaces or returns.

Comment: @petebocken bingo!

Comment: @petebocken To check the username you can try http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-current-user.php or the code on the comment.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Current script owner: root

Comment: @petebocken That's strange. Are you absolutely sure about the filename and path? Are you accessing the file using Apache?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel no simply running the php script.  #php serverpilot-ssl-apply.php

Comment: @petebocken What happens when you run `cat /root/certs/mydomainredacted.com/ssl.key`?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I get the key text from the file as expected

Comment: @petebocken And when you run a PHP file with ``<?=`cat /root/certs/mydomainredacted.com/ssl.key`;``, what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue #1

`$vardomainname` has an incorrect string. Missing characters, **too many characters**, hidden characters, or just plain wrong; idk.

or

`"/root/certs/$vardomainname/ssl.key"` does not exist.

or

You do not have access to `"/root/certs/$vardomainname/ssl.key"`

---

### Issue #2

Change:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
```

into

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
```

Per the [**CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS** section of `curl_setopt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) you need to provide either a PHP array or properly [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the array into a string. JSON is not appropriate here.

---

### Last but not least

You are blind without [`curl_errno`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) and [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)

Comment: There is definitely something wrong with the string, because there is a carriage return after the string(5) "test

Comment: @petebocken If you do not have access to the file in order to properly fix it then try `$vardomainname = trim(file_get_contents("temp_serverpilot-domainname.txt"));` However, if you do have access then try checking to make sure the file is not saved as UTF-8 with BOM because the BOM adds extra bytes to the file.

Comment: Yes! I originally saved the txt file on my Mac and sure enough there was a carriage return that came across.  OK, great that solves that issue.  Thanks!

Comment: @petebocken You're welcome, please feel free to accept my answer.

Comment: Trimming the extra carriage return from all 4 files using "trim(file_get_contents)" ultimately fixed all of my problems.  I did not need to make the changes to the curl commands that you recommended in "Issue #2".  Thanks again! Accepting your answer.